# I executed a shell script with “usr/bin/expect“ in a docker container within "docker exec" command, then the keyword "expect" seems to be ignored

Tags: linux, docker, shell, expect

There is a c program running in the docker container named main. And I need to do some additional operations with the process everyday.
So I put a shell script named gdb_op.sh in "/opt" path of a docker container.
The content of gdb_op.sh is:

```
#/bin/bash

file_path="$1"
/usr/bin/expect <<-EOF
set time 30
spawn gdb - `pidof main`
expect "(gdb)"
send "set \\\$len = ((int (*)(char*))getFileLen)(\"${file_path}\")\r"
send "set \\\$buf = malloc(\\\$len)\r"
send "set \\\$file = ((void*(*)(char*, char*))openFile)(\"${file_path}\", \"rb\")\r"
send "p/x ((int (*)(void*, int, int, void*))readFile)(\\\$buf, \\\$len, \\\$file)\r"
send "p/x ((int (*)(void*))closeFile)(\\\$file)\r"
send "detach\r"
send "q\r"
expect eof
EOF
```

And I run this script within "docker exec" like:

```
docker exec -i $container_id bash -c "cd /opt;./gdb_op.sh $file_path"
```

Then it seems like the line of 'expect "(gdb)"' was ignored.

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1
...
Attaching to process 3146162
...
<*))getFileLen("...")
0x00007fce324eb8f3 in clock_nanosleep () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) set $buf = malloc($len)
<))openFile("...", "rb")
<t, int, void*))readFile)($buf, $len, $file)
Invalid cast.
(gdb) p/x ((int (*)(void*))closeFile)($file)
$1 = 0x0
(gdb) detach
Detaching from program: /home/vfabric/bin/main, process 3146162
[Inferior 1 (process 3146162) detached]
(gdb) q
```

The line of getFileLen, openFile and readFile, part of the charactors of casting missed , and "set $len =" missed too. This makes the script unable to use.
Is there any solution?

The target is to do the gdb operations (in script) to the process out of the container. These gdb operations have to be contained in a script so it's easy to maintain.

Comment: I'd start by writing an expect script directly instead of trying to make a giant string in a shell script. Fewer levels of evaluation = fewer ways for things to get treated differently than expected. (heh)

Comment: Thx, I tried to use an expect script, and it runs in the same way. But thanks for this attempt, I found the difference between "docker exec" and executing shell script inside the docker container. When I use "docker exec", there is a line`--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--` above the line `<*))getFileLen("...")` I am doubting how to deal with this line.

Comment: Why not write gdb script? `to do the gdb operation` Why not do gdb operations? why expect? `sh -c 'gdb $(pidof main) -ex this -ex that -e read_commands_from_this_file'`